# Has anyone had any luck connecting a SharePoint list to SuccessFactors?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I found [this resource](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/17/improve-employee-productivity-with-sap-successfactors-and-microsoft-office-365/#:%7E:text=SAP%20SuccessFactors%20and%20Microsoft%20are,between%20SuccessFactors%20and%20Office%20365) that says you can connect O365 to SuccessFactors, but I specifically want to connect a SharePoint list so I can push something to the continuous feedback tool in SuccessFactors. Has anyone done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SuccessFactors does not directly intergrate with SharePoint Online. And there is no integration between the Continuous Feedback tool and SharePoint lists.

However, you can take advantage of Power Automate and SuccessFactors API. If you create a Cloud flow that is triggered when a SharePoint list item created, you can send an HTTP request to the SuccessFactory via their API:

[image]

Note that the HTTP connector shown on the screenshot is a premium connector that will require a premium license.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble creating the URI. From what I've found, you need to assemble it, it's not something nestled somewhere you can go and copy. This is proving to be tricky. Do you know of any resources I can look at? What I've found isn't working for me.